# How to find a specific word in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, find, wordsearch

I am trying to figure out how to search a word search puzzle for words in the word bank.
I have a 1D list with each row as a separate string within that list.

For example:

```
m=num rows
n=num columns

grid=['A B C D E F G','H I J K L M N','O P Q R S T U V','W X Y Z A B C']

wordbank=['APPLE','BANANA','ORANGE','BERRY','GRAPE']
```

The expected output is as follows with the first number being the row number and the second being the column number in which the first letter of each word was found:

APPLE   4 2

BANANA  8 4

ORANGE 14 9

BERRY   7 1

GRAPE   9 8

How can I go through the grid and search for each word in the word bank and return its index ?

Also, in addition to searching left to right horizontally, how can I search the grid vertically for the words as well?

I am feeling pretty lost on going about this as I am a beginner to programming.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I am supposed to write an output file in the following format:          APPLE  4  2                                                            BANANA 9  4                                                           ORANGE 14 8                                                            With the first number being the row number and the second number being the column number in which the first letter of the word was found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the columns you can use a piece of code like

```
for i in range(n): # where n is the num of columns...
    for x in grid:
        print(x[i], end='')
```

and that will provide an exit like

```
AHOW    BIPX    CJQY    DKRZ
```

TIP:
If you want to do a check from right to left you can always parse a string like

```
myword = 'Hello'
myword[::-1] # This will return 'olleH'
```

This can be useful for check for concordances both in vertical and horizontal checks.